# osmdroid android project from existing code crash

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded a project from https://code.google.com/p/bikeroute/ but when I try to create the project from this code I have this error in eclipse.
does anyone know where this error comes from ? and what I have to do to correct it ?

```
could not set the project description for 'OpenStreetMapViewer' because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file system
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project and select `Refresh`. If that doesn't work right click again and select `Close Project` then open the project again.

You didn't tell how you have imported the project to eclipse. But somehow it seems you have changed the file `.project` outside of eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded it and create a new project in eclipse from this code.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens for me because I have my workspace on Dropbox, just refresh it and it should work fine.

Another option might be right-click -> "Android-Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties"

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and tried different ways. In order to do the methods described in the other answers, we need to see the projects listed in the project explorer but in my case, I did not see the projects listed in the Project Explorer, though I see the project folders getting created in the Workspace.

I tried different ways but the one below worked for me.

1. First, delete the project folder that is created in the Workspace (under Windows Explorer). Click **Refresh** in the **Project Explorer** and **Eclipse** would show you a *prompt* to delete the references of the deleted project folder. Click ***Yes*** to make sure the project reference is deleted from the .metadata.
2. Secondly, do the following:

   > e.g. if the project is located in D:\temp\Project-01, then *delete the .project file that is found in this location* and then import the project again (**WITHOUT** the .project file in the source location) from the **Eclipse -> New -> Import** (from *Existing Android Code Into Workspace*).

Eclipse automatically create the .project file for you.